# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function locale_accept_from_http()

Tags: php, backend

мне надо определить локаль клиента с помощью обычных функций в php. Но когда я запускаю выводит фатальную ошибку:

> **Call to undefined function locale_accept_from_http()**.

Запускал эту функцию уже везде, и постоянно выводит эту ошибку.

**Вот варианты этой функции:**

ООП: `Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);`

Процедурный стиль: `locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);`

Пользуюсь локальным сервером "OpenServer".

Answer (score 2):

У Вас отключено расширение intl.

В Ваших настройках OpenServer в файле php.ini, найдтите строчку:

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

И удалите символ `;`.

Если строчки нет, то добавьте сами:

```
extension=php_intl.dll
```

Сохраните и перезагрузите сервер.

Comment: OpenServer при перезагрузке сбрасывает файл к стандартам, и ; появляется снова

Comment: Хм, попробуйте здесь:
Настройки - Дополнительно - Конфигурация - PHP